# How to enumerate all the registered sources for an EventLog

Tags: windows, event-log, event-viewer

If I select to filter the "Application" log in the EventLog viewer, I can see a lot of Sources registered with the "Application" log. How could I programmatically enumerate all these sources via C#? And it seems I cannot register my own evento source with "Application" and "System" log, why?

BTW: The concept of "event source" is really confusing...

Answer (score 3):

There might be a more appropriate .NET or Windows API you could reference for this, but the info is ultimately stored in the registry under the Eventlog service key.  The service's root key is here:
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog`

Most of the subkeys under that key will be the various event logs on the system including `System` and `Application`.  For each log, it will contain a bunch of additional subkeys that represent the registered sources for that log.  So just enumerate the subkeys to get your list.

On XP/2003 OSes, the log's subkey also contains a REG_MULTI_SZ value called `Sources` that should match the list of source subkeys.  That value appears to no longer be used on Win7/2008 R2 machines (not sure about Vista).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet to enum the sources.
Note:

- Each SourceName must be unique per machine, NOT per log. (Thats why I didnt use SourceName like a sub class of EventLog)
- You need admin privilges to enum logs. Use in Settings / Windows-Settings:
  `<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">`
  `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`
  `</requestedPrivileges>`
- If you create a new source you must wait a while until it is registered at system
- If you switch a source to another log, you must restart between deleting and (re-)creating source.

---

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports  Microsoft.Win32

Public Class ClsEventSources

Friend Class MySourcesInfo
  Friend LogName As String
  Friend SourceName As String
End Class

Private MyEventLogList As New List(Of EventLog)
Private MySourceList As New List(Of MySourcesInfo)

Private Const RegEventLogPath As String = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\"

  Private Sub New()

    MyEventLogList = EventLog.GetEventLogs.ToList

    For Each Ev In MyEventLogList 

        For Each SubKeyName In _
           Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegEventLogPath & _
                                  Ev.Log).GetSubKeyNames

            MySourceList.Add(New MySourcesInfo With _
                      {.LogName = Ev.Log, .SourceName = SubKeyName})
        Next     

    Next

  End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for the System.Diagnostics.EventLog class, which should reveal all.

Comment: Alas, System.Diagnostics.Eventlog doesn't have a function to list all registered event sources. You can only check if an event source with a given name exists. But if you don't know the name you can't get a list of existing event sources.